# java double double check singleton instance error

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am trying to implement double check but getting this error.

```
static UserPayments singletonInstance;

public static volatile UserPayments getSingletonInstance(){
if (null == singletonInstance) {
    synchronized (UserPayments.class){
        if (null == singletonInstance){
            singletonInstance = new UserPayments();
        }
    }
}
return singletonInstance;
```

}

Illegal modifier for the method getSingletonInstance; only public, protected, private, abstract, static, final, synchronized, native & strictfp are permitted

Comment: or more precisely, move it from the method signature to the field declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volatile can not be used for methods, only for fields.

From the [Java Language Specification:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

> 8.3.1.4. volatile Fields
>
> [...]
>
> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, volatile
>   fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.
>
> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model
>   ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable
>   (§17.4).

As such, you may mark the actual field `singletonInstance` with volatile, but not the method which retrieves the instance.